# Which Values (High or Low) are better in Android's getGsmSignalStrength()

Tags: android, gsm, signal-strength

I'm playing around with reading the signal strengths in a small Android App, and was wondering if anyone has tested this (or just knows) of the documented values (0-31, 99) which value is better.

By asking which is better, I mean, does 0 represent no signal, or perfect signal.

I'm running an HTC Incredible on Verizon, so I can confirm the 99 is no GSM antenna, but I could not find any other items on GSM

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The values are defined in the GSM standard TS 27.007, section 8.5 (Google it, or see [here](http://www.xs4all.nl/~m10/mac/downloads/3GPP-27007-630.pdf))

From the standard:

```
0        -113 dBm or less  
1        -111 dBm  
2...30   -109... -53 dBm  
31        -51 dBm or greater  

99 not known or not detectable
```

Which means - 0 is low, 31 is good.

Comment: `Which means - 0 is low, 31 is good.` is exactly what people need to know

Comment: 31 is 'red hot', rather than 'good'. When I used to be a GSM cellular radio planner, we used to plan for a signal strength of -93dBm (i.e., 10) or more at the phone. So, I'd say anything above 10 can be regarded as adequate/good - esp. for 3G and 4G technologies.

Comment: how to convert dBm to percentage?